# Roughly how many functions are in the Clojure core libraries?

Tags: function, clojure, common-lisp

Common Lisp has over 700 functions in its core libraries. Roughly how many does Clojure have in its libraries?

(Where 'core library' is defined as everything you get access to when you include `[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]` in your `project.clj`)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*(Update: Inspired by this question, I have released [Varspotting](https://github.com/michalmarczyk/varspotting), a Leiningen plugin and library for producing reports on data of this kind. The reports for Clojure 1.5.1 are displayed in the README; see also my comment below for the numbers. The minor differences between those counts and the ones in the answer below are a result of the REPL environment including certain bindings which Varspotting omits from its counts.)*

Using Clojure 1.5.1.

The `clojure.core` namespace:

1. Public Vars:

   ```
   (count (ns-publics 'clojure.core))
   ;= 591
   ```
2. Public Vars which hold non-macro functions (the filter function is meant to exclude the 6 Vars which hold maps, see below for how to find them; there are not sets or vectors to exclude at this time):

   ```
   (->> (ns-publics 'clojure.core)
        vals
        (filter #(not (.isMacro %)))
        (map deref)
        (filter (every-pred ifn? (comp not map?)))
        count)
   ;= 477
   ```
3. With `#(.isMacro %)` in the `filter` above, we find there are 76 public macros.
4. The 32 public Vars which do not hold function-like values can be discovered with this snippet:

   ```
   (->> (ns-publics 'clojure.core)
        vals
        (remove (comp ifn? deref)))
   ```
5. Use `(filter (comp map? deref))` instead of the `(remove ...)` in the above to find the 6 Vars holding map values.

Same as 2. for all namespaces in the Clojure jar (skipping the deprecated `clojure.parallel` and additionally excluding the two Vars holding vectors; there are no sets to exclude at this time; hopefully haven't missed anything else):

```
(dorun (map require '[clojure.core clojure.data clojure.edn clojure.inspector
                      clojure.instant clojure.java.browse clojure.java.javadoc
                      clojure.java.io clojure.java.shell
                      clojure.main clojure.pprint clojure.reflect clojure.repl
                      clojure.set clojure.stacktrace clojure.string
                      clojure.template clojure.test clojure.walk clojure.xml
                      clojure.zip]))

(->> (mapcat ns-publics
             '[clojure.core
               clojure.data
               clojure.edn
               clojure.inspector
               clojure.instant
               clojure.java.browse
               clojure.java.javadoc
               clojure.java.io
               clojure.java.shell
               clojure.main
               clojure.pprint
               clojure.reflect
               clojure.repl
               clojure.set
               clojure.stacktrace
               clojure.string
               clojure.template
               clojure.test
               clojure.walk
               clojure.xml
               clojure.zip])
     vals
     (filter #(not (.isMacro %)))
     (map deref)
     (filter (every-pred ifn? (comp not map?) (comp not vector?)))
     count)
;= 676
```

For macros, the total count is 99.

Comment: If you'd like to reproduce these results at the REPL, keep in mind that the `*1`, `*2` and `*3` Vars store the values of the last three evaluated expressions and may distort results of filtering on the value of the Vars. This could be fixed by filtering on the root value (with `.getRawRoot`), but I didn't bother -- it's simple enough to type these into a fresh REPL or clear the last values by evaluating `nil` three times.

Comment: This is a brilliant answer. For the sake of clarity - is your final answer to the question 676?

Comment: Inspired by this question, I have released [Varspotting](https://github.com/michalmarczyk/varspotting), a Leiningen plugin and library for printing reports on such data. For Clojure 1.5.1 built-in namespaces, the reported counts are as follows (here a "proper" function is a function as created by fn, in contrast to callables such as sets and maps): 831 public Vars, of which 6 are initially unbound, 39 are marked dynamic (of these 6 hold proper functions), 658 hold proper functions, 98 are registered as macros and 17 hold non-proper callables.

Comment: Don't forget to count every method on every Java class included in `rt.jar`, which are also available to every Clojure program.

Comment: @amalloy: I thought about that, by I consider most of those to be implementation details, much like non-public Vars. I could do a separate tally for those, I suppose.

Comment: Oh, I agree that most of the stuff in clojure.jar is implementation details, but I said rt.jar. Having access to java.io.Socket, java.util.Collections, and stuff like that, is an integral part of the "standard library" in Clojure.

Comment: Oh, sorry, misread the jar name. Yeah, that would bump the counts somewhat noticeably. :-)

Comment: Ouch, sorry, I reported buggy counts in the earlier comment; correct counts are as follows: 844 public (6 unbound, 39 dynamic, of the latter 6 are proper functions), 670 proper functions, 99 macros, 17 non-fn callables.